# connect to windows 10 VM through xen

Tags: ssh, xen

I created win10 VM on my Ubuntu 16.04 OS.
i already download all the relevant packages for ssh .

[i started the ssh service and i got this ssh's status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7piN.jpg)

[when i tried to connect the vm i got connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liRjP.jpg)

note: the firewall is disable  (in VM as well)
 can someone help please?
what should i do ? should i configure something on win10 VM?

Comment: Did you installed ssh in Windows 10? Because you are trying to connect to it, ok?

Comment: Related: https://noise.paulos.cz/post/windows10-14352-ssh-server/

Comment: i already installed openssh . what should i do to run it in client mode?

Comment: note : i already ran the mkgroup and mkpasswd commands then  i searched for ssh service in controlPanel-services but i didn't find nothing

Comment: @Redbob can you help please?